# Evaluate consistency of 3d printed lines

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm fairly new to OpenCV but have some experience with programming.

In 3d printing there's this thing called Linear Advance/Flow calibration, where we print a few lines changing some value between them and then evaluate the most consistent line of them all.

Like these (the red squares are pointing defects on the lines and the green one is showing the optimal line):
[image]

[image]

Evaluating these myself often makes me confused so I decided to try using OpenCV to do that. What would you suggest for me to accomplish this?

In terms of defining a strict set of rules I think we could use the average width of the entire line and the one with less deviation or higher score would be the best. At the moment I have nothing written because I don't really know what to look for.

Thank you

Comment: How can you define a "uniform line"?

Comment: @stateMachine sorry if I've not used the correct terms but I mean the most consistent line. Will edit the question

Comment: I mean, can you _define_ it in strict terms so you can program it as a **rule/set of rules**? Maybe you are looking for the line with most constant "width", or maybe you are looking for the straightest line, or maybe both... What's the definition of "uniform line" for your particular problem? Explain why there are two different colored rectangles on the image, why are the rectangles seemingly highlighting a different number of lines? Also, you don't show what you have tried and you don't attach your original, un-annotated, images, so it is difficult to help you out.

Comment: @stateMachine So in terms of defining a strict set of rules I think we could use the average width/most constant width of the entire line and the one with less deviation or higher score would be the best. At the moment I have nothing written because I don't really know what to look for. Thank you for your patience xD

Comment: first, you need to locate those lines, because the picture doesn't align them with the pixel grid. I'd suggest user input for this, i.e. picking (clicking on) the four outermost corner points, entering a number of lines, and that then spans a grid of start and end points for all lines. this is strictly speaking a homography (2nd pic) but an affine transform might suffice. -- when you have that, you can use `warpAffine` (or warpPerspective) and some transformation matrices to ***sample a band along each line***. such a band you can then analyze for brightness/thickness along its length.

Comment: the top picture looks good, the bottom one does not. -- the top one is taken top-down, hence requires very mild alignment. the bottom one requires perspective transformation. -- you should physically avoid reflections in the substrate. either print on matte substrate (not glass directly), or darken the room and only illuminate such that the white lines are visible, nothing else. make sure the image isn't overexposed, i.e. the white lines don't clip into absolute white.

Comment: Is that transparent glass or a shiny surface? If glass, you could illuminate from behind with a diffuse light source. That is the most precise way to measure sizes of objects.

Comment: That's a glass surface I've taken from google images as an example of what the process would look like. I was thinking about creating those markers people make so the program can locate them and align on the printed files and instructing people to take a picture from top/down with a filament colour with good contrast with the surface